# the pillow make the image being more size than before

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I use python pillow to do a easy gif image reverse,but I found that the image has become more size(10m) than before(1m). Anyone know how to make it?
And here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence
from PIL import ImagePalette
with Image.open('sd.gif') as im:
    if im.is_animated:
        frames = [f.copy() for f in ImageSequence.Iterator(im)]
        frames.reverse()
        frames[0].save('out.gif', save_all=True, append_images = frames[1:])
```

Comment: I'm unclear what you mean by 10m & 1m? Do you  mean the size on the disk?

Comment: yeah, do some words I used cause you confused?

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell for sure without examining the actual images, but I can guess what likely happened:

Some gifs are optimized with a method that finds pixels in each frame where nothing is changing (or changing only very slightly) from frame to frame, and make them transparent instead of storing the color for each pixel, to reduce the amount of data. For some gifs with large static areas in many consecutive frames this can be very efficient way to reduce file size.

When you are reversing the GIF, the frames must be unoptimized first, otherwise there would be transparent areas without any data. This can increase file size quite a bit. The difference may vary from one image to another.

You probably can solve this by running some gif optimization algorithm after the new image is created.